# difference between openTK and cloo?

Tags: opencl, opentk, cloo

what is the difference between using openTk and cloo for developing openCL applications?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The original plan was to have OpenTK provide low-level OpenCL bindings and develop Cloo as a higher-level, object-oriented wrapper around them. At some point, it became obvious that it would be more efficient (develpoment-wise) to spin off the low-level OpenCL bindings from OpenTK into Cloo.

To answer your question: use Cloo for OpenCL and use OpenTK for rendering. They are distinct, yet complementary, projects.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. By installing openTK only, I can see openCL samples. So why is cloo better than openTK for openCL applications?

Comment: OpenTK no longer offers OpenCL bindings. They have been moved to Cloo.